# How to use set ranges

Tags: vba, excel, select, range

I am looking for a way to improve on a better way to write a piece of code that'll look if the there are clients from "First List" in "Second List" and copy the data over to a sheet named "Found".

It goes something like this:

```
Dim row As Long, row2 As Long, found as Long
Dim ID As String, prtGtId as String, GtId2 as String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
prtGtId = "B"
GtId2 = "D"
row = 2
row2 = 2
found = 0
Do While row <= Cells(Rows.Count, prtGtId).End(xlUp).row
    ID = Cells(row, prtGtId)
    Sheets("Second List").Select
    Do While row2 <= Cells(Rows.Count, GtId2).End(xlUp).row
        If (ID = Cells(row2, GtId2)) Then
            Rows(row2).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Found").Select
            Rows(2).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Sheets("First List").Select
            Rows(row).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Found").Select
            Rows(2).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Sheets("Second List").Select
            found = found + 1
        End If
        row2 = row2 + 1
    Loop
    Sheets("First List").Select
    row = row + 1
    row2 = 2
Loop
Sheets("Blank").Select
Cells(2, 3) = found
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This is a simplified version of my actual code (which is much larger and containing a lot of early exits to the loops as well as organizing alphabetically), but right now I'm mainly concerned that using the ".select" function is what's consuming most of my processing time.

I know I've seen there's another way using

```
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, prtGtId),Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, GtId2).End(xlUp).row, prtGtId))
For Each Cell in rng
    Code
Next Cell
```

or something along those lines, but I can't seem able to find a detailed tutorial that goes further than "It's much faster this way".

Considering that I need the format in the rows to be kept when copying them over to the "Found", is there a way to change this to make it go faster?

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate and select emulate user keystrokes and even if you set Application.ScreenUpdating to false, you don't need to really select objects. You should generally avoid these methods (see here an interesting article about why and when to select:http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/27/beginning-vba-select-and-activate/). Declare variables (set rng...) or deal directly with the objects instead.

```
Sub test()
Dim row As Long, row2 As Long, found As Long
Dim ID As String, prtGtId As String, GtId2 As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
prtGtId = "B"
GtId2 = "D"
row = 2
row2 = 2
found = 0
Do While row <= Sheets("First List").Cells(Rows.Count, prtGtId).End(xlUp).row
    ID = Sheets("First List").Cells(row, prtGtId)
   ' Sheets("Second List").Select
   With Sheets("Second List")
    Do While row2 <= .Cells(Rows.Count, GtId2).End(xlUp).row
        If (ID = .Cells(row2, GtId2)) Then
            .Rows(row2).Copy
            Sheets("Found").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Sheets("First List").Rows(row).Copy
            Sheets("Found").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            found = found + 1
        End If
        row2 = row2 + 1
    Loop
    End With
'    Sheets("First List").Select
    row = row + 1
    row2 = 2
Loop
Sheets("Blank").Cells(2, 3) = found
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

you see few lines less and no more select. See also how works "with" statement (used here as an example) which can be very useful.
(I assume you launch your macro with sheet "First List" activated, that's why I add Sheets("First List")) Programming that way also avoid this kind of error (so you can launch your macro without worrying about wich sheet is activate)

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a short example of what you may be able to do in the code you provided. Instead of Rows(row2).Select you could also write Set CurrentRow = Rows(row2)
Of course you would have to declare the CurrentRow as a range beforehand (Dim CurrentRow as Range)
It would also be advisable to release the CurrentRow variable when you are done with it by using Set CurrentRow = Nothing
The only thing that you need to know is that what you put behind the equals sign in the Set statement should produce a range object.
Most of the time lines of code that use .Select can be rewritten to not select the item but, for instance, putting it in a variable. This generally speeds up the code and you do not have to reset the selection after your code is done.
I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create an array with all the IDs from the First List, then check if you find the same IDs in the Second List, and create an array with the row numbers of the double IDs.

With the last array you could make one big selection with all the rows you need, and copy it all at once.

I don't know if this speeds it up a lot but maybe you can try.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the Select statements entirely. Try this, no ranges needed.

```
If (ID = Cells(row2, GtId2)) Then
    Sheets("Second List").Rows(row2).Copy
    Sheets("Found").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("First List").Rows(rw).Copy
    Sheets("Found").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    found = found + 1
End If
```